# Why doesn't the Unix command work in the Perl script?

Tags: perl, unix

I want to extract part of a text file starting at a certain pattern and store it in another file. My Perl script takes a single argument as the input text file. So far, I have:

```
my $INPUT = $ARGV[0];
my $LINES_TO_DUMP = 4000;
my $startline = `egrep -n "^PATTERN" $INPUT | head -1 | cut -f1 -d:`;

# THIS LINE DOESN'T WORK
system("tail +$startline $INPUT | head -$LINES_TO_DUMP > extracted.txt");
```

When I run my program, it gets 'stuck' running the second command (the `egrep` command works, and stores the correct number). I've run the command in my terminal to make sure it works.

What is going wrong?

Comment: But when I run it in the terminal it takes only half a second?

Comment: You might want to sanitize your `$INPUT` The way you are using it now it could be used to cause **a lot of damage**. Imagine a user passes something like `| rm -rf /`. Make sure it's a file name. Maybe with `die 'wrong argument' if $INPUT =~ m/[|]/;` Also **do not try with my sample input, it might wipe your system!!!**

Comment: You're right, I really need to add proper error checking/handling...I'm always lazy and don't add it until the end when I absolutely must

Comment: You could also use Getop::Long or similar. Or taint-mode. That would help a lot here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's likely that your `$startline` has a newline in it, as it's consumed from command output. You should confirm this and then use `chomp()` on `$startline` prior to your `system()` call.

Here's the [perldoc for chomp](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) as suggested.

Comment: This seems like it should be a comment.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Comments require reputation 50.

Comment: @razor What you posted is not an answer in its current form. You could do several things to make it answer-worthy. e.g: look at the page @simbabque linked. You could also link to the perldoc page for `chomp`.

Comment: In addition to what @Hunter said, you can also rephrase it to sound more like you know what you are talking about. That usually gives people who read your answer more confidence and they are more likely to trust you (and upvote).

Comment: I can't accept it for another 3 minutes, but I will when I can

Comment: Also don't "respond" to comments in your answer. Just edit it so that new readers see it as a good source of information. Just leave a comment saying something like "thanks for the suggestion @hunter, I added that to the answer", upvote the comment and move on. That way you will create a high-quality answer that half a year later someone new instantly understands.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions to a newbie. Advice taken.

Comment: I would suggest to have the ``chomp`` link to the perldoc, drop the line with with the _Here's the..._ and instead have an example. That would be along the lines of `my $startline = `egrep ...; chomp $startline; # ...`. But in a block. :)